# rails 4 multiple image uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, multifile-uploader

Currently the admin can create an assignment with only one image being uploaded. I am trying to let the admin upload multiple files/images for users to see on the assignment show page. I've seen other ways of achieving this but I cannot find a way to implement it into my application without breaking it.

**controller: assignments_controller.rb**

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :admin_access, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
     @assignments = Assignment.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end


   def show
     @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
     @assignment = Assignment.new
   end  

   def create
     @assignment = current_user.assignments.build
     @assignment.name = params[:assignment][:name]
     @assignment.description = params[:assignment][:description]
     @assignment.picture = params[:assignment][:picture]


     if @assignment.save
       flash[:notice] = "Assignment was saved successfully."
       redirect_to @assignment
     else
       flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating assignment. Please make sure there is a name and description."
       render :new
     end
   end

     def edit
     @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
     end

      def update
     @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])

     @assignment.name = params[:assignment][:name]
     @assignment.description = params[:assignment][:description]
     @assignment.picture = params[:assignment][:picture]

     if @assignment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Assignment was updated successfully."
       redirect_to @assignment
     else
       flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving assignment. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
      end

   def destroy
     @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])

     if @assignment.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "\"#{@assignment.name}\" was deleted successfully."
       redirect_to action: :index
     else
       flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the assignment."
       render :show
     end
   end

     private 

     def assignment_params
         params.require(:assignment).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
     end
end
```

**model: assignment.rb**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :submits, dependent: :destroy
        belongs_to :user
        validates :name, length: { minimum: 1, maximum:120 }
        validates :description, length: { minimum: 1 }
        mount_uploader :picture, AssignmentpicUploader
end
```

*The submits model/controller submit the students work to the admin*

**controller: submits**

```
class SubmitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :my_sanitizer
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_user


  def index
      @submits = Submit.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

   def show
     @submit = Submit.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
      @submit = current_user.submits.build
   end

   def create
      @submit = current_user.submits.build(submit_params)

      if @submit.save
         redirect_to submits_path, notice: "The assignment #{@submit.name} has been uploaded."
      else
         render "new"
      end

   end

   def destroy
      @submit = Submit.find(params[:id])
      @submit.destroy
      redirect_to submits_path, notice:  "The assignment #{@submit.name} has been deleted."
   end

   private
      def submit_params
      params.require(:submit).permit(:name, :attachment)
      end

end
```

**model: submit.rb**

```
class Submit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assignment
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
end
```

**uploader: assignmentpic_uploader.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AssignmentpicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick


   storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :large do
     process :resize_to_fit => [500, 700]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

**views/assignments:**

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Assignment</h1>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>Guidelines for topics:</p>
     <ul>
       <li>Make sure the topic is appropriate.</li>
       <li>Never insult dogs.</li>
       <li>Smile when you type.</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <%= form_for @assignment do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :name %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter assignment name" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :description %>
         <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter assignment description" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :picture %>
      <%= f.file_field :picture %>
      </div>
      <br />
       <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'button' %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

index.html.erb

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
<h1>Assignments 

    <% if current_user.admin %>
     <%= link_to "New Assignment", new_assignment_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
     <% end %>
        <hr>
</h1>
  </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10">
 <!-- #7 -->
     <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
       <div class="media">
         <div class="media-body">
           <h3 class="media-heading">
 <!-- #8 <--> 
             <%= link_to assignment.name, assignment %>
           </h3>
                                   <!-- Date/Time -->
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 
        <%= time_ago_in_words(assignment.created_at) %> ago
        </p>
           <small>
             <%= assignment.description %>
           </small>
         </div>
       </div>
       <hr>
     <% end %>
   </div>
   <br>

   </div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Assignment</h1>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>Guidelines for topics:</p>
     <ul>
       <li>Make sure the topic is appropriate.</li>
       <li>Never insult dogs.</li>
       <li>Smile when you type.</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <%= form_for @assignment do |f| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :name %>
         <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter assignment name" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :description %>
         <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter assignment description" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :picture %>
      <%= f.file_field :picture %>
      </div>
      <br />
       <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'button' %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

show.html.erb

```
 <h1><%= @assignment.name %>

 <% if current_user.admin %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Assignment", edit_assignment_path, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm round' %>
    <%= link_to "Delete Assignment", @assignment, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm round ', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this assignment?' } %>
<% end %>
 </h1>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <p class="lead"><%= @assignment.description %></p>
 <!-- #10 -->
     <% @assignment.submits.each do |submit| %>
       <div class="media">
         <div class="media-body">
           <h4 class="media-heading">
             <%= link_to submit.name, submit %>
           </h4>
         </div>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>


   <div id="img">
    <%= image_tag @assignment.picture.url(:large) %>
  </div>

  </br>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <%= link_to "Submit Assignment", new_submit_path(@assignment), class: 'button' %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**views/submits:**

index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <h1>Student Work</h1>
   <hr>
</div>

 <% if current_user.admin %>
<small>Hold "CTRL" + "F" to search for assignment or student name.</small>
 <% end %>
<br />
<br />

<table class = "table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>View Assignments</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
      <% @submits.each do |submit| %>

         <tr>
            <% if can? :destroy, submit %>
            <td><%= submit.name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "View Assignment", submit.attachment_url %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Delete",  submit, method: :delete, class: "button", data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{submit.name}?" } %></td>
            <% end %>
         </tr>

      <% end %>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="text-center">
<h1>Submit Assignment</h1>
</div>
<hr>

<% if !@submit.errors.empty? %>
   <div class = "alert alert-error">

      <ul>
         <% @submit.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
      </ul>

   </div>
<% end %>

<div class = "well">
   <%= form_for @submit, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <br />
      <%= f.label :attachment %>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
      <br />
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button" %>
   <% end %>
   </div>

   <p>Please include "ASSIGNMENT NAME - YOUR NAME" in the field above</p>

   <br />
   <p> Example:</p>

   <small> assignment 1 - Bob Smith</small>
```

**schema.rb**

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160930021506) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "picture"
  end

  add_index "assignments", ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id"

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "phone"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "submits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "attachment"
    t.integer  "assignment_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username",               default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

sorry if this is too much or too little information.
Thank you in advance too all the wonderful people here willing to lend a helping hand.

Comment: If you can afford it - buy Rails in Acition 4 - turn to page 299 - they handle this exact problem two ways - you can do it as a fixed number of attachments alloed and screen for them not being used OR you can use fancy jquery and AJAX to allow them to add as many attachments as they want.

Comment: including your code snippets is important; but for the sake of a Rails question on StackOverflow it's best to include only the relevant portions. You haven't given much space to describing where the problem lies (or an error).